# AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class with multiple data sources

Tags: hibernate, multiple-databases

Have two classes:

**basepackage.a**.Entity1

and

**basepackage.a**.b.Entity2

Entity1 has @ManyToMany relationship to Entity2

**Entity1:**

```
@Entity
Table(name = "Entity1")
public class Entity1 {

// fields here

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "Entity1_TO_Entity2",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Entity1_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Entity2_ID")
)
private Set<Entity2> entities2;
```

**Entity2:**

```
@Entity
Table(name = "Entity2")
public class Entity2 {

// fields here

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "entities2")
private Set<Entity2> entities1;
```

Have an error when application context started.

> AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Answer (score 0):

Error reason was in bed configuration of multiple data sources. 
Next configuration is looking to *sub packages as well*

```
 basePackages = {
            "basepackage.a"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your annotations look fine. Here are the things to check:

1. make sure the annotation is **javax.persistence.Entity**, and not **org.hibernate.annotations.Entity**. The former makes the entity detectable. The latter is just an addition.
2. if you are manually listing your entities (in persistence.xml, in hibernate.cfg.xml, or when configuring your session factory), then make sure you have also listed the Entity1 and Entity2.
3. make sure you don't have multiple Entity1 and Entity2 classes in different packages, and you've imported the wrong one.